# Materialize CSS text input -> Getting a space between input and underline

Tags: textarea, materialize

I'm getting an extra line-feed in the textarea widget between the underline and the input area.

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

You can see the extra space below the default text and the line for the widget

My code is pretty straight-forward I think:

```
           <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col m4">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">linear_scale</i>
                <textarea id="r1-value" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="r1-value">R1 Value</label>
            </div>
            <div class=col m4">

                  <select class="browser-default" name="r1-units">
                      <option value="1">&#8486</option>
                      <option value="2">k&#8486</option>
                      <option value="3">M&#8486</option>
                  </select>
                <label>Resistor Units</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col m4">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">linear_scale</i>
                <textarea id="r2-value" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="r2-value">R2 Value</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $('select').formSelect();
              });
        </script>
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Materialize default text area shouldn't be like this. Take a look at https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html also please add code snippet or jsfiddle in your question.